# average of groupby elements python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

so I have this list looks like that:

```
58308.803701    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   64
58308.815456    149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170   50602 6   60
58308.815524    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   52
58308.817244    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   57
58308.828987    149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170   50602 6   52
58308.829133    149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170   50602 6   57
58308.829169    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   52
58308.912361    132.227.127.170 50603   86.4.136.93       443   6   64
58308.912497    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216     443   6   95
58308.912568    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216     443   6   96
58308.912977    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216     443   6   847
58308.913411    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216     443   6   154
58308.913484    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216     443   6   233
....
....
....
```

and I want to group each similar lines (with the same five columns in the middle) and show in the output the minimal of the first column and the average,median,mean,min,max,...(all possible statistic metrics) like the following:

```
58308.803701                            132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   64
58308.815456                            149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170   50602 6   60
min of(58308.815524,58308.817244)       132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   min/max/avg/...of(52,57)
min of(58308.828987,58308.829133)       149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170   50602 6   min/max/avg/...of(52,57)
58308.829169                            132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15      443   6   52
58308.912361                            132.227.127.170 50603   86.4.136.93       443   6   64
min of(58308.912497,..,58308.913484)    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216     443   6   min/max/avg/...of(95,96,847,154,233)
....
....
....
```

so here is the code I wrote so far and trying to make it work:

```
from itertools import groupby 
import re 
import numpy as np

tstFile=open("output","w+") 
with open('dataInput','r') as d:
      f1 = ([x for x in line.split()] for line in d)
      for a,b in groupby(f1,key=lambda x:x[1:6]):
          tstFile.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" %(min(x[0] for x in b)),min(x[6] for x in b)),max(x[6] for x in b)),np.average(x[6] for x in b)),np.mean(x[6] for x in b)),np.median(x[6] for x in b)),np.std(x[6] for x in b)))
tstFile.close()
```

but nothing really seems to work, it only work for the min and max but to get each result I have to only use one argument... like this :

```
tstFile=open("output","w+")
with open('dataInput','r') as d:
    f1 = ([x for x in line.split()] for line in d)
    for a,b in groupby(f1,key=lambda x:x[1:6]):
        tstFile.write("%s\n" %(min(x[6] for x in b)))
tstFile.close()
```

Any help PLEASE !

Comment: Correct indenting in the second code sample. Nice you use `with` context manager for opening file, use it also for the "output" file. Consider using `csv` to read source data and write it out. And for grouping, do first some smaller scale testing on command line to get familiar with it. A lot of fun in front of you.

Comment: what indenting please?
I ve tried before working with csv files and it was a big mess.. x)
for the grouping it works well, i have problems with the average/min/... do u suggest a specific tutorial or somth
Thank yooou

Comment: the line `tstFile=open("output"...) .. whith open(..` which shall come to two lines. Sorry, I was refering to wrong code sample.

Comment: yess you're right, i ve corrected it, thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with csv-files, it's generally advised to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). I've included a sample code below which demonstrates how you could solve this problem.

If your input file is tab-delimited, change to `delimiter='\t'` and remove the `skipinitialspace=True` in `csv.reader` - the tabs weren't present in the sample input, but they may have disappeared during copy/paste.

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

with open('data.csv') as in_file, open('out.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')
    for key, group in groupby(reader, key=lambda r: r[1:6]):
        col0, col6 = np.array(list(group))[:, [0, 6]].transpose().astype(float)
        writer.writerow([min(col0)] + key + [int(min(col6)), int(max(col6)),
                                             np.mean(col6)])
```

Output (I added some tabs to increase readability):

```
58308.803701    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15    443     6   64  64  64.0
58308.815456    149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170 50602   6   60  60  60.0
58308.815524    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15    443     6   52  57  54.5
58308.828987    149.13.32.15    443     132.227.127.170 50602   6   52  57  54.5
58308.829169    132.227.127.170 50602   149.13.32.15    443     6   52  52  52.0
58308.912361    132.227.127.170 50603   86.4.136.93     443     6   64  64  64.0
58308.912497    132.227.127.170 50599   94.31.112.216   443     6   95  847 285.0
```

Comment: Thank you very Much! it works like magic
After all cvs sounds to be great I think I ll focus on learning its tricks from now on :3

Comment: Np :) I've updated the answer a bit, it's easier and probably faster to use numpy to transpose and cast to float than using `map` and `zip(*lst)`